# Технические требования к Linux Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu

Кто-нибудь знает, какие тех. требования к системе на убунту 11.04? Весь ихний сайт перекопал и не нашел.

Comment: Кто реально ищет, тот находит.

Comment: Hello, this is Linus Torvalds, and I pronounce Linux as [ˈlɪnʊks]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyNarwhal/ReleaseNotes#System_Requirements